# When to use UserPassesTestMixin vs PermissionRequiredMixin

Tags: django

It seems to me that these mixins can accomplish similar goals in different ways. I can let someone access a view by checking if the user has a permission with `PermissionRequiredMixin`, or I can use `UserPassesTest` and write a `test_func` that checks if a user is in a particular group, or even check the permission there.

I'm new to Django and am having trouble knowing when to use one versus the other. In isolation I understand what they do, but not well enough to understand where they are appropriate.

A couple scenarios I've come across I'm not certain which is best

- Which should I use to limit access to certain views?
- In an app where users can create objects, limiting updating/deletion of these objects to the creator

Comment: `UserPassesTest` can define any test, since it calls a function. `PermissionRequiredMixin` can be seen as a "special" `UserPassesTest` that checks permissions, since that is a common use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **PermissionRequiredMixin:** Verify that the current user has all specified permissions.
- **UserPassesTestMixin:** Deny a request with a permission error if the `test_func()` method returns `False`.

As the name suggests `PermissionRequiredMixin` only checks the permissions that are defined either in **`permission_required`** attribute or **`get_permission_required()`** method.

But, the **`UserPassesTestMixin`** is much generic version, which helps you to check any number of arbitrary conditions. For example, you can check the logged-in user's email domain, or any custom attributes, or values etc.

---

#### Example-1

```
In this example, both are equal.
from django.contrib.auth import mixins
from django.views import generic


class TestPermissionView(mixins.PermissionRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    permission_required = [
        'foo.add_bar',
        'foo.change_bar'
    ]


class TestUserTestView(mixins.UserPassesTestMixin, generic.CreateView):
    def test_func(self):
        req_perms = [
            'foo.add_bar',
            'foo.change_bar'
        ]
        
        return self.request.user.has_perms(req_perms)
```

In this example, both classes behave in the same way

#### Example-2

```
class TestUserTestView(mixins.UserPassesTestMixin, generic.CreateView):
    def test_func(self):
        # this  checks the email domain of the user
        allowed_domains = ['foo.com', 'bar.co.in']
        return self.request.user.email.split('@')[1] in allowed_domains
```

In this example, we are checking the user's email domain. As you can see, this example can not be re-written using `PermissionRequiredMixin` class.

Comment: And now the fun part: combine the two: the user has the permission, however only for domain foo.com.